# How to loop through 4 lists in and identify common elements in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, for-loop

I have extracted the first two lists called station1 ad station2 from a csv file, which contains the connections between two stations, time and the line. however, it just contains the id numbers of the stations and not the name. The IDs of the stations are not in order.

The other two lists called stationId and stationName - I have extracted from a csv file too, which contains the station IDs in order from 1 to 272 and the station names.

I would like to identify the name of the station by the ID and the line too and put them into another list or variable and make a graph based on this so I can perform an A-star search for the shortest distance.

For example:

station1Name: Baker Street, lineName: Westminster, lineName: Jubilee

```
station1 = ["11", "11", "49", "82", "54", ...]
station2 = ["163", "12", "87", "11", "82", ...]
line = ["1", "3", "5", "6", ....]
time = ["1", "2", ....] 

stationId = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", ...]
stationName = ['Acton Town', 'Aldgate', 'Aldgate East', 'All Saints', 'Alperton', 'Angel', 'Archway', 'Arnos Grove', ...]
lineName = ["Victoria", "Piccadilly", "Northern, ...]
```

Thanks

I tried to do a nested for loop for the first list and the second but that didn't work.

```
for x in range(len(station1)):
    for y in range(len(station2)):
       if station1[x] == station2[y]:
```

Comment: Suggestion: use `csv.DictReader` to import your csv file if it has headers and you'll get back a reasonable `dict` instead of an unlabeled list of values.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -3):

try this:

```
for i in zip(station1,station2):
print(i) #('11', '163') p.s. (station1[0],station2[0])
         #('11', '12') (station1[1],station2[1])
```

Comment: Please explain _why_ you think your answer will solve the question instead of dumping code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).